# why orientation of views change after setting elevation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-linearlayout

after I set elevation for my LinearLayout my imageView which should on my LinearLayout goes behind it, what is the problem? here are my codes:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_cardview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/login_iut_logo"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I want my ImageView to be on LinearLayout. it works well till not to set elevation for LinearLayout. I set elevation because I wanted its shadow.

I want to have something like this:
[image]

but after I set elevation for LinearLayout it turns to something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your image to be inside the linear layout you should nest it like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
  app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:elevation="10dp" />


  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:elevation="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This should do the trick! (without changing much of your code)

Comment: no, I don't want to my image be inside of LinearLayout. in fact I want my image to be 'on' my LinearLayout.

Comment: Ah I understand what you are trying to achieve. I'm updating my answer but you shouldn't have something less elevated than another thing and make it show on top (it breaks the material metaphor).
Just add elevation to the imageView.
The relative layout displays all it's same elevation children with the latest on top, but elevation takes priority over the order.

Comment: thanks, it works but it causes other issues, I don't want my imageView has a shadow.

Comment: It's hacky but you can set its shadow to be transparent with:
    android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/transparent"
    android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/transparent"

:)